# SwiftUI Text alignment with maxWidth not working

Tags: swift, text, swiftui, alignment

I have the following code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Test")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .font(.subheadline)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .alignmentGuide(.leading) { d in d[.leading] }
            .background(Color(.blue))
    }
}
```

But as you can see on the image bellow, it does not left align the text. Does anyone knows why this is happening?
Maybe because i'm using maxWidth the alignmentGuide thinks it's already left aligned?

[image: result]

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Because alignmentGuide has effect in container with other subviews. In this case you need to align `Text` within own frame.

Here is solution

[image: demo]

```
Text("Test")
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .font(.subheadline)
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)   // << here !!
    .background(Color(.blue))
```

Comment: wow I didnt expect that. I wanted to alphabetically declare them so sequence does matter